# Where do the kings of the earth come from in Revelation 21:24?

Tags: revelation

Revelation 21:24(KJV)

> 24 And the nations of them which are saved shall walk in the light of
>   it:  and the kings of the earth do bring their glory and honour into
>   it

To my understanding in Revelation 20 there would be the white throne judgement where all that were found not written in the book of life are thrown into the lake of fire. Then in Revelation 21 we see the new Jerusalem, where all that are saved should be inside the new city.

So where would the kings of the earth that bring their glory & honor into the new city come from? Could there be a chronological discord here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is found in Revelation 1:

> 4 John to the seven churches which are in Asia: Grace be unto you, and peace, from him which is, and which was, and which is to come; and from the seven Spirits which are before his throne; 5 and from Jesus Christ, who is the faithful witness, and the first begotten of the dead, and the prince of the kings of the earth. Unto him that loved us, and washed us from our sins in his own blood, 6 **and hath made us kings and priests unto God and his Father**; to him be glory and dominion for ever and ever. Amen. [-Revelation 1:4-6 (KJV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=revelation+1%3A4-6&version=AKJV)

And in Revelation 5:

> 9 And they sung a new song, saying, Thou art worthy to take the book, and to open the seals thereof: for thou wast slain, and hast redeemed us to God by thy blood out of every kindred, and tongue, and people, and nation; 10 **and hast made us unto our God kings and priests: and we shall reign on the earth**. [-Revelation 5:9-10 (KJV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=revelation+5%3A9-10&version=AKJV)

The kings that bring their glory and honor to the Lamb are the redeemed, who were from every nation and people. They were washed from their sins and made kings by Jesus and reign on the earth.

Everyone in the New Jerusalem does not stay perpetually within the city, for the very next verse makes a point to bring out the fact that the city gates are never shut, implying that the inhabitants come and go as they please:

> And the gates of it shall not be shut at all by day: for there shall be no night there. [-Revelation 21:25 (KJV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=revelation%2021%3A25&version=AKJV)

Some of the kings go out into the earth, but still make trips back to the New Jerusalem in order to bring their glory and honor to the Lamb.

Answer (score 0):

That seems strange considering the many generations that are born during the 1000 year reign of Christ on the earth. Some will be judged and some will remain after the white throne judgement. These are the ones mentioned as the nations of the saved. Not ones who were martyred, tested, endured tribulation. They reside in the hevenly kingdom but not within the city/temple of God. Only privileged ones who God has chosen are within.

Comment: Hi Ray, welcome to BH-Stack Exchange, we are glad you are here. I don't quite follow how your post answers the question, could you elaborate on your thoughts? Please be sure to take the [site tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) and read up on how this site is a [little different](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives#803) than other sites around the web. Thanks!